# android how to reload main activity after exit the apps

Tags: android, exit

Halo guys,

My apps is set to be exit after double click the back button,
but if i open the apps again, it just return to the previous page that i exit.

How can i truly exit the apps after double click back button, while i will return to the previous page if i exit by home screen button?

here is my exit code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: have u tried intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); flag
which clears all the activities and points to the top of the Activity Stack.

Answer (score 0):

The finish() method is used to remove your reference form the stack trace, While you perform the double back press use this method

Comment: finish() just end the current activity, is it possible to finish all of the activity?

Answer (score 0):

In onPause of your activity

```
if(doubleBackToExitPressedTwice == true){
    finish();
}
```

finish() is used to tell the current activity to stop and exit.

Comment: finish() just end the current activity, is it possible to finish all of the activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
```

these code just make you relanuch the home app. if your want to finish your activity,call finish().

Comment: finish() just end the current activity, is it possible to finish all of the activity?